# Replacing particular value in hashtable

Tags: javascript, c#

I have declared a hashmap in javascript

```
formdata["id"]={"1","2","3",...}
formdata["value"]={"one","two","three",....}
```

Now, I want to update value for `id=3, (value="three") to (value="four")`.
Is there any way to do this in javascript?

Comment: The question is tagged for C# and jQuery. jQuery is not a programming language. JavaScript and C# are programming languages, but the code you listed doesn't look like either. Can you be more specific about what language you're using and the actual code you are trying to get working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you must understand the difference between javascript and jquery. Very briefly, javascript: the language, jquery: a framework over the language. 
So that's a javascript question and must be resolved in javascript.

Also your definition is bad, the array must be defined so:

```
formdata["id"]=[1,2,3,...];
formdata["value"]=["one","two","three",....];
```

A way based on your formdata var:

```
var index = formdata["id"].indexOf("3");
var value = formdata["value"][index];
```

Another way to define the structure like a "real dictionary":

```
var formdata = {
    "1": "one",
    "2": "two",
    "3": "three",
    ...
};
var value = formdata["3"];

// Update value:
formdata["3"] = "three_2";

// Add value:
formdata["4"] = "four";

// Remove value
delete formdata["3"]
```

Comment: I know the method u mentioned. But I want to know how one can update value if hashtable is defined like this

Comment: @rakesh showing real code in the post would give some clarity to "like this"... Very unclear So far what you actually have.

Comment: Added samples of Add, Update and Remove values to "dictionary". Please 
@RakeshChandra check as response if it fits to you.

Comment: As @AlexeiLevenkov points, for better help, publish the real (or very similar) code.